# Webdriver-based *simple* program not working?(Element not Visible(Yes it is!))

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, google-search

I'm trying to create one of the *simplest* programs in python with selenium. Literally all it does is look up "rosebud" on google. It keeps returning element not visible(in reference to the SEARCH BUTTON!) Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
    def test_login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        Query = "q"
        Search = "//input[@value='Google Search']"
        Life = "Rosebud"

        QI  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(Query))
        SI  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(Search))

        QI.clear()
        QI.send_keys(Life)
        SI.click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()`
```

Comment: When you start typing in the search box on google.com, do you see what happens to that search button? This is why it's not visible.

You probably need to find the search button after you sendkeys, and use this selector `"//button[@value='Search']"` or `"//button[@value='Search']/span"`. Let me know if that works and I'll post as answer.

That will find the button attached to the search bar since those other buttons disappear.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! In fact, I used it on another much more complicated selenium program, so thank you.

Comment: Good to hear! I went ahead and posted as an answer if you wouldn't mind accepting.

Answer (score 0):

When you start typing in the search box on google.com, the page can change and those buttons disappear.

You probably need to find the search button after you sendkeys, and use a selector for the search icon within the search box. Something like this:

```
Query = "q"
Search = "//button[@value='Search']" # or ""//button[@value='Search']/span"
Life = "Rosebud"

QI  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(Query))

QI.clear()
QI.send_keys(Life)

SI  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(Search))
SI.click()
```